# How can i alter my program to allow this object to only react to a single touch?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch, xcode7, game-physics

I am making a basketball game. My problem is when I shoot the ball, i can then touch the ball in mid-air again, which i do not want. Once the user shoots the ball I do not want touch to have an effect. Here is my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?
{
    touching = false
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    if ball.frame.contains(location){
        touchingPoint = location
        touching = true
    }
    }
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        touchingPoint = location
    }
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if touching{
        let dt:CGFloat = 8.25/29.5
        let distance = CGVector(dx: touchingPoint.x-ball.position.x, dy: touchingPoint.y-ball.position.y)
        let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
        ball.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity
    }
}
```

What can i add to my program so that a touch won't have any effect once the ball has been shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you shoot the ball disable userInteraction

```
ball.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

then enable it again when you want them to be able to touch it

Comment: Hell Yes @LukePatterson

Comment: Are you somehow linked to questions from my profile? or did you come across this randomly. Just curious because that was literally the fastest correct answer I've ever seen and because i know you helped me with a previous question. @LukePatterson

Comment: @DeanSponholz haha I have the web page for newest swift questions open and I will occasionally go there to answer questions when I'm bored at work. I did notice I've answered your questions before!